# How do you delete albums (or large groups of songs) from your iOS device using iTunes Match?

Tags: itunes, ios, music, itunes-match

I forced my iPhone to download everything in iCloud (create All Music playlist, download, wait...). Now I want to delete about 25% of my music from the device. iOS 7 only allows you to delete one song at a time. How can I delete albums or ideally large groups of music at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, turn off iTunes Match (temporarily) on your iOS device: Settings > Music > iTunes Match > Off

Connect the iPhone (or iPad) to iTunes. Under DEVICES, find yours and highlight Music. Manually organize and delete songs, albums, artists, genres, etc.

Once iTunes is done updating, disconnect. Reenable iTunes Match.

Comment: +1 had same issue, this works for me - thanks!  Ridiculous that Apple makes it so hard.  As long as we are dependent on physically connecting to a computer with iTunes, Apple music services like iTunes Match are not truly "cloud" at all.